# editing PATH variable on mac

Tags: macos

How to edit PATH variable on mac (Lion). I cannot find any file where I can add paths. can someone guide me about it?

Whats the file name? .profile or .bash_profile???

and where I can find it?
I have tried

```
echo 'export PATH=/android-sdk/tools:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: I find this question very useful, but maybe you should ask it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Add this line to your ~/.zshrc file. export PATH=$PATH:<your_new_path>. You can do this multiple times as you are appending the new path variable to the old one.

Comment: [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12629/495859) ([https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12629/495859](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12629/495859)) is the question on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 239):

Open and edit `/etc/paths` using any text editor, e.g. [`vi`](https://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/).

```
$ sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Note: each entry is separated by a new line

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Save and close the file. The path updates will be in effect when you start a new terminal session.

Comment: I had to open a new terminal to get this to work, not use one that was already open.

Comment: sudo emacs /etc/paths :/

Comment: @SittingBull you're welcome to use whichever editor suits you :)

Comment: Works on a new tab of the Terminal after saving the `/etc/paths` file. Doesn't really require a restart of the Terminal.

Comment: why does
 `$ sudo vi /etc/paths`
give less output than 
`$ tr ':' '\n' <<<$PATH`
?

Answer (score 38):

Based on my own experiences and internet search, I find these places work:

`/etc/paths.d`

`~/.bash_profile`

Note that you should open a new terminal window to see the changes.

You may also refer to this [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard)

Answer (score 11):

You could try this:

> 1. Open the Terminal application. It can be found in the Utilities directory inside the Applications directory.
> 2. Type the following: echo 'export PATH=YOURPATHHERE:$PATH' >> ~/.profile, replacing "YOURPATHHERE" with the name of the directory
>    you want to add. Make certain that you use ">>" instead of one ">".
> 3. Hit Enter.
> 4. Close the Terminal and reopen. Your new Terminal session should now use the new PATH.

Quoted from [ketio.me tutorial (archived copy)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111024015635/https://keito.me/tutorials/macosx_path).

Comment: Yes I have tried that command but it seems nothing happens after pressing enter, I restarted the terminal but still path is not added.

Answer (score 10):

`environment.plst` file loads first on MAC so put the path on it.

For 1st time use, use the following command

```
export PATH=$PATH: /path/to/set
```

Comment: put the same export command in "environment.plst" file to keep it permananet.

Comment: Where is this file supposed to be located?

Answer (score 5):

use

```
~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

(see Runtime Configuration Guidelines)

Comment: You an actually, use cd ~/  then open .zprofile in MacOS