# Muscle Multiple Sequence Alignment with Biopython?

Tags: python, alignment, bioinformatics, biopython

I just learned to use python (and Biopython) so this question may bespeak my inexperience.

In order to carry out MSA of sequences in a file (FileA.fasta), I use the following code:

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
inp = 'FileA.fasta'
outp = 'FileB.fasta'
cline = MuscleCommandline(input=inp, out=outp)
cline()
```

I get the following error:

```
ApplicationError
... 
 Non-zero return code 127 from 'muscle -in FileA.fasta -out FileB.fasta', message '/bin/sh: muscle: command not found'
```

I know that this has something to do with the executable not being in my working PATH. The Biopython tutorial suggests that I update the PATH to include the location of Muscle Tools and it gives an example of this for Windows, but I don't know how to do this for MAC.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you know where you installed `muscle`. If, for example, you installed muscle in:

```
/usr/bin/muscle3.8.31_i86darwin64
```

then you [edit `/etc/paths`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703041/editing-path-variable-on-mac) with:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Each entry is separated by line breaks:

```
/usr/local/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Add the appropriate path (in this example `/usr/bin`) to the list. Save with [`wq!`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-vim-save-and-quit-command/)

Now, make sure the `muscle` is on your path. Try to run

```
muscle -in FileA.fasta -out FileB.fasta
```

If that works, the BioPython code should work as well.