# php -v and phpinfo() loading different php.ini file

Tags: php, macos, xampp, php-7.1

I wondered now with XAMPP (MAC) that why the php.ini file is taking wrong in php cli.

phpinfo(); returning correct version 7.1.

[image]

php -v returning like below..

```
sh-3.2# php -v
PHP 7.0.15 (cli) (built: Jan 22 2017 08:50:55) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

sh-3.2# which php
/usr/local/bin/php

sh-3.2# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I want to make the php-cli version as 7.1 to start my development.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you have an old php version installed? If so, change the PATH

Comment: i dont know how to change the path. please give an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703041/editing-path-variable-on-mac

Comment: should I want to set the path to phpinfo ini file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override the path of PHP to use the MAMP path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path)

Comment: @rndus2r It will be better if you are giving a solution other than sharing links. I tried many links and not work this yet.

Comment: the first link answer your question "I don't know how to change path". the second answer the question "how to set pathinfo to phpinfo ini file". ;)