# PATH variable not working?

Tags: terminal, path

So I have a program installed on my mac called cleos. If I type cleos in the terminal it executes, but it doesnt work. I'm guessing because its an old version.
I have the correct version in /Documents/eos/build/programs/celos and I can execute by navigating to that directory and typing ./cleos. When I type ./cleos it works fine.

So my question is how do I remove the old cleos from the terminal and attach the new cleos?

When I do `echo $PATH`I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sb:Users/arc/Documents/eos/build/programs/cleos:/Users/arc/scripts:Users/arc/Documents/eos/build/programs/cleos/`
```

Which points to the new cleos. But then why is it that when I type cleos without the ./ it seems to run the old broken version?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this a programming question? You're looking for [apple.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: You've got a typo in your path.  `Users/arc/Documents/eos/build/programs/cleos` should be `/Users/arc/Documents/eos/build/programs/cleos` (the entry right after `/sb`

Comment: Not a mac user but found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703041/editing-path-variable-on-mac?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
maybe something that might help you.

Comment: As mentioned, you have a typo in your `$PATH`, you can probably resolve it by: `sed -i '' 's@sb:Users@sb:/Users@' ~/.bash_profile`