# Node version not updating after "nvm use" on mac

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am trying to update my local node version from 8.9.0 to 8.10.0 using nvm. But it's not getting reflected. Here's what I tried:

`node -v`

`-> v8.9.0`

`nvm use 8.10.0`

`-> Now using node v8.10.0 (npm v5.5.1)`

`node -v`

`-> v8.9.0`

I am unable to get why it won't change. Please let me know what have I done wrong.

Comment: You might have Node installed in multiple paths, with `nvm` only managing one. What does `which -a node` tell you?

Comment: It says

`/usr/local/bin/node`, 
`/Users/prabhjotrai/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/node`, 
`/usr/local/bin/node`
```

Comment: I see there are multiple paths, what fix would you suggest?

Comment: Have you installed Node via Homebrew as well? If so, [`brew uninstall node`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919540) would uninstall the instance at `/usr/local/bin/node`, leaving the other managed by nvm. Otherwise, you can try to [modify your `PATH` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703041) (or any shell configs which may alter it before opening) to give the nvm path priority.

Comment: nvm maintainer here - the issue is likely that your PATH isn't set up properly in your shell profile file. the easiest solution is to move the nvm sourcing lines to the end of it.

If that still doesn't work, please file an issue on the github repo.

Answer (score 19):

Adding few notes about my experience on debugging this problem.

First, I started out with the command provided by [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski) `which -a node` and got the same output as op:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
/Users/<my-user>/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/node
```

Moving on to the next comment by Jonathan: *Have you installed Node via Homebrew as well?*, I tried uninstalling node by `brew uninstall node` and got and error that said it could not uninstall node as there was another program dependent on it. `yarn`.

And then realised that `brew` had installed its own version of node because I installed `yarn` through `brew`, which was overwriting the node version that I wanted to use through nvm.

Uninstalling brew's version of `yarn`+`node` fixed my problem.
I still needed yarn, and now I have to install `yarn` globally for each node version managed by nvm.

Inconvenient, I agree. But so is maintaining twenty thousand versions of node for each project so not very different in my opinion.

All of this was done on M1 MacOS and your output might vary based on your system.

Comment: You could also try `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node`

Comment: In my case, I just needed to `brew uninstall node` (and let nvm manage it).

Comment: In my case doing `brew uninstall node` led to an error ("no such keg...") because I installed node with a specific version so I had to do `brew uninstall node@18`

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure that when you input `arch` on command prompt, then output is `i386`.

This is achieved using `Rosetta`.

Following sequence of commands on terminal worked: -

```
nvm install 8.10.0
nvm install --lts
nvm ls
brew upgrade
arch -arm64 brew install n
n
```

Now select node version 8.10.0 using up or down arrow keys in keyboard and then quit from command prompt using `command+q`

Please do not try `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node`

Answer (score 0):

Just check you environment variables first. It might be mapping to node@8.9.0.
You need to remove the environment variable first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also using volta. Volta may take precedence.

Use `which -a node` to verify.

If that is the case, use `volta pin node@version` to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `nvm` sourcing lines at the bottom of your `.zshrc` shell configuration. This ensures that nvm's `node` path has a higher priority than Homebrew's `node` path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this issue https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-wizard/issues/518 . To check, if some deps override the nvm setup, please run the below command

```
brew uninstall node
```

And check nvm after that

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I moved the following to the bottom of ~/.zshrc file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Open new tab/restart terminal

Answer (score -3):

First check your nvm version installed on your local system. go to command prompt and type "nvm list" If you don't see the versions 8.10.0 in the list then install using command : "nvm install 8.10.0" and then try "nvm use 8.10.0".

For reference : http://www.tutorial-points.com/2018/11/nvm-installation-on-windows.html