# Installing javacc on mac with terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, installation, javacc

I have downloaded javacc-5.0 and tried to follow various different guides to no avail.

I unzipped the package, modified the PATH variable to contain `../javacc-5.0/bin/lib/javacc.jar` directory and ensured that all the correct files are executable. However, a `which javacc` command gives no output and trying to run the javacc exec has also given the error `Could not find or load main class javacc` (the jar file is definitely there in the lib directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `...../javacc-5.0/bin` directory, there should be a file called `javacc` that should looks something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
JAR="`dirname $0`/lib/javacc.jar"

case "`uname`" in
     CYGWIN*) JAR="`cygpath --windows -- "$JAR"`" ;;
esac

java -classpath "$JAR" javacc "$@"
```

If so, [edit your PATH variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703041/editing-path-variable-on-mac) to include `/....../javacc-5.0/bin`, i.e. the absolute path of that `bin` directory.  There is no need for the PATH variable to include `/....../javacc-5.0/bin/lib/javacc.jar`; so take that out.

Start a new terminal.  In the new terminal, check the PATH variable with `echo $PATH`. Try `which javacc`.   Try `javacc`.

Answer (score 0):

javacc can easily be installed using Homebrew:

```
brew install javacc
```

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/javacc