# How do I add Python 3.8 to the path on Mac and do I need Pycharm to use Python?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.8

I just downloaded Python 3.8 on my Mac but I don't know how to add it to the path. I don't even know where to find the path. Do I need to download an IDE to use Python? I got Python Launcher and IDLE when I downloaded Python 3.8.

Comment: You don't need an IDE

Comment: I think, you can install python 3.8 via pyenv on Mac only. I tried to do with pip a few weeks ago and found that pip has only 3.7 I am not 100 % though. You do not need an IDE to run Python. You can invoke python scripts from the Terminal.

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific if you want help on your install

Comment: [editing PATH variable on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703041/editing-path-variable-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

I think, currently you can install python 3.8 via `pyenv` on Mac only. I tried to install 3.8 with `pip` a few weeks ago and found that pip has only 3.7. I am not 100 % sure, though. So I would recommend to install it via pyenv. Find a description how to do it on [the github repo of pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#how-it-works)

You do not need an IDE to run Python. You can invoke python scripts from the Terminal. If you use PyCharm, you can easily select the python version for the virtual environment PyCharm creates on a per-project basis.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I downloaded Python from python.org