# How to install Python 3 support with Vim 8 using Homebrew

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew

When installing Vim on Mac OS with `+python3` support I get the following error:

```
% brew install vim --with-python3
Usage: brew install [options] formula

...

Error: invalid option: --with-python3
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`+python3` [is now enabled by default](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/326a46e319deafeca962f07c397ea29788d598ca/Formula/vim.rb#L51) on Vim via Homebrew as of 2019. Older instructions out on the internets are not accurate (and I will not link to them to avoid raising their search ranking).

Simply install/upgrade via Homebrew:

```
% brew uninstall vim # optional, only if you previously installed it 
% brew install vim
```

Verify `+python3`:

```
% /usr/local/bin/vim --version
...
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
...
```

Note, you still will have the system default Vim installed and it *may* be in your PATH before your Homebrew installed version, so if you do `vim --version` and it doesn't show `+python3`:

1. try restarting your terminal
2. try `alias vim=/usr/local/bin/vim`
3. try adjusting your PATH variable to put Homebrew's Vim first. "[editing PATH variable on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703041/editing-path-variable-on-mac)" has additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Just write: `rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'` then, `brew link --overwrite python@3.9`